# Letreiro em TextView - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer o efeito de letreiro em um `textview`
o texto é muito grande, e eu não quero quebrar linha, quero que o texto se movimente da direita pra esquerda na horizontal.

**O texto que eu quero manipular e o que contem as informações da musica**
[image: O texto que eu quero manipular e o que contem]

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/scrollingText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="Texto aqui"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"/>
```

Comment: Tenho como alterar a velocidade ?